# How to handle post request of a ModelChoiceField form in django? Attribute Error?

Tags: python, django, forms, post, django-forms

I want to create a form where the user can select a model object, but the choices are filtered based on the user. I want to then pass that object to the html template page, so I can display the object fields on the page.

I got the form to display the objects correctly, so the get function is working, but when the user submits the form, I'm getting an Attribute Error that says "'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'". So I'm assuming there's something wrong with my post function.

**Error Stack Trace**

```
File "/Users/wsm-app/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/wsm-app/polls/views.py", line 244, in post
    form = calendarForm(request=request.POST)
  File "/Users/wsm-app/polls/forms.py", line 25, in __init__
    user = request.user
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

**forms.py**

```
class calendarForm(forms.Form):
    inputDate = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Select a date", queryset = None, empty_label="No date selected")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if request:
            user = request.user
            self.fields['inputDate'].queryset = Analysis.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('sessionID__startDate')
```

**views.py**

```
class MultiView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'polls/analysis.html'

    def get(self,request):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            form = calendarForm(request=request)
            userid = self.request.user.id

            args = {'form': form,'obj':Analysis.objects.filter(user=userid).order_by('sessionID__startDate').last()}
        else:
            args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, self.template_name,args)


    def post(self,request):
        form = calendarForm(request=request.POST)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            if form.is_valid():
                obj = form.cleaned_data['inputDate']
                form = calendarForm(request=request)
                args = {'form':form,'obj':obj}
        else:
            form = calendarForm(request=request)
            args = {'form':form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Answer (score 0):

User is inside of request object not inside of POST parameters

```
def post(self,request):
    form = calendarForm(request=request)
```

you are getting `request.POST.user` as you pass `request.POST` instead of request itself ( user is accessed through `request.user`

Comment: this still doesn't help handle the post request :/